# Why doesn't pyngrok detect my config file?

Tags: python, pyngrok

I am trying to use my own configuration file with `pyngrok` but I don't understand why it does not detect it, my project needs to be run forcefully with `sudo`, therefore `ngrok` does not detect the configuration file in the `root` home directory for some users, it is that's why I want to mount my own configuration file in my project directory, here is my code:

```
from pyngrok import ngrok, conf
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re

def ngrok_start ():
        file = Path (".config/ngrok.yml")
        if file.exists():
                os.system("kill -9 $(pgrep ngrok)")
                ngrok.DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH = ".config/ngrok.yml"
                ngrok.connect(443, "tcp")
                while True:
                        ngrok_tunnels = ngrok.get_tunnels()
                        url = ngrok_tunnels[0].public_url
                        if re.match ("tcp://[0-9]*.tcp.ngrok.io:[0-9]*", url) is not None:
                                print ("Ngrok TCP:" + url)
                                break
```

With my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ngrok.py", line 27, in <module>
    ngrok_start ()
  File "ngrok.py", line 20, in ngrok_start
    ngrok.connect (443, "tcp")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyngrok/ngrok.py", line 181, in connect
    timeout = pyngrok_config.request_timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyngrok/ngrok.py", line 321, in api_request
    status_code, e.msg, e.hdrs, response_data)
pyngrok.exception.PyngrokNgrokHTTPError: ngrok client exception, API returned 502: {"error_code": 103, "status_code": 502, "msg": "failed to start tunnel", "details": {"err": "TCP tunnels are only available after you sign up. \ nSign up at: https://ngrok.com/signup\n\nIf you have already signed up, make sure your authtoken is installed. \ nYour authtoken is available on your dashboard: https: //dashboard.ngrok.com/auth/your-authtoken\r\n\r\nERR_NGROK_302\r\n "}}
No handlers could be found for logger "pyngrok.process"
```

My script is in the lib folder and my configuration file in `.config/ngrok.yml`, in which I have my token but I can't detect it, I hope you can support me, thanks.

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLQNP.png)

Comment: Please, *never* post your credentials online.  You'll need to regenerate your token.

Comment: did you follow the following https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-authtoken to install your token?

Comment: ready I have edited the image to censor a part of the token, I want to authenticate my token not manually but through pyngrok, but I can't get good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the docs](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#config-file), the `DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH` variable is in the `conf` module, not the `ngrok` module. So change `ngrok.DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH =`  to `conf.get_default().config_path =` .

Comment: I also tried with conf, in fact I have it imported as seen in my code, but I got the same error however I want.

Comment: also check the PyngrokConfig thing, but I would like it to work directly with my own config file

Comment: Using `pyngrok_config = PyngrokConfig(config_path="/some/path")` and then passing `pyngrok_config` to `connect()` is probably the better approach.

Comment: It already prints the link, but I get this message `No handlers could be found for logger" pyngrok.process `, is there any way to avoid it?
"

Comment: You need to [configure a logger for your application](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file). This is only an issue on Python 2, as Python 3 has a `lastResort` logger that it will fallback to in cases where you haven't setup a basic configuration.